# Is it possible to find the time an email was first modified/read in Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-interop, outlook-addin

I am currently working on a very simple C# add-in for Outlook that will iterate specific folders and output specific details about messages to a CSV file.  I have that part complete, however **I was wondering if there is a way to tell when a message is first modified or read?**  I know that I can see the last modified time, but I am hoping that I am just missing something in the API that those more experienced than me know of.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that. the best you can do is read the PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED MAPI property (DASL name "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003") - it will tell the time last time the message was replied to or forwarded.